# Picard number of Prym Variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It is known that, for a generic curve $C$, $End(J(C)) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, hence picard number is one. Is this  true for  Prym Variety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true for a generic curve, but for a *very general* curve (= outside countably many strict subvarieties of the moduli space). The same is true for Prym varieties, because the closure of the locus of Prym varieties contains the Jacobian locus ("Wirtinger's construction").

Comment: Can you suggest me some reference for this?

Comment: Birkenhake-Lange, *Complex Abelian varieties*, Remark 12.4.3.

Comment: Can you explain it little more?

Comment: I am not sure what you want me to explain. In a given family $\mathcal{X}\rightarrow B$ of projective manifolds, those with Picard number $\geq 2$ form a countable union of subvarieties of $B$ (a given cohomology class being algebraic defines one such subvariety, and you have countably many cohomology classes). All you have to do is to make sure that none of these subvarieties is equal to $B$, so it is enough to show that your family contains *one* 
 manifold with Picard number 1.

Comment: But how do you know that the desired conclusion is *false* for a generic curve $C$? Is this somehow related to the work of Maulik and Poonen (*Néron-Severi groups under specialization*)?

Comment: No, sorry, since the OP wrote "*a* generic curve" I took it in the old sense of "in an open subset of the moduli space". Certainly it is true for *the* generic curve, or the generic Prym.

Comment: @abx I am little bit confused about your statement for generic curve. Is picard number is one for generic case in any dimesion? Can you also suggest some reference?

Comment: Yes. You might have a look at [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.4781.pdf) mentioned by René.

Comment: I'm almost positive that $\mbox{End}(J(C))\simeq\mathbb{Z}$ for the general curve $C$; I believe Pirola showed something like this using degenerations of abelian varieties, but I can't think of where I saw it.